# JAXB error by calling SOAP client stub generated from wsimport command with JDK 1.6

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsimport

I am getting the below exception while calling the client stub generated from wsimport command with JDK 1.6.
Below piece of client code is used:

```
AppLookupServiceService service = new AppLookupServiceService();
AppLookupService port = service.getAppLookupService(); //This line causing the below exception (generating port from service)
```

*
The same code is working fine with client stub generated with wsimport and jdk 1.7

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModel.createJAXBContext(RuntimeModel.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModel.postProcess(RuntimeModel.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ServiceContextBuilder.processAnnotations(ServiceContextBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ServiceContextBuilder.completeServiceContext(ServiceContextBuilder.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.processServiceContext(WSServiceDelegate.java:136)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:288)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:174)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:94)
    at com.lookup.webservices.AppLookupServiceService.getAppLookupService(AppLookupServiceService.java:50)
    at com.client.AppLookupClient.main(AppLookupClient.java:21)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 8 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://webservices.lookup.com}lineOfBusiness.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.lookup.dto.LookUpServiceRequestDTO.lineOfBusiness
        at com.lookup.dto.LookUpServiceRequestDTO
        at protected com.lookup.dto.LookUpServiceRequestDTO com.lookup.webservices.GetLookUpServiceDetails.getLookUpService
        at com.lookup.webservices.GetLookUpServiceDetails
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://webservices.lookup.com}flex1.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.lookup.dto.LookUpServiceRequestDTO.flex1
        at com.lookup.dto.LookUpServiceRequestDTO
        at protected com.lookup.dto.LookUpServiceRequestDTO com.lookup.webservices.GetLookUpServiceDetails.getLookUpService
        at com.lookup.webservices.GetLookUpServiceDetails
```

*

When I generate the client stub from wsimport with JDK 1.7, then I am able to get the response by calling the client stub, but with JDK 1.6 I am getting the above exception.

I searched every where but didn't find anything helpful.

Please suggest why is this happening with JDK 1.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without having a look at the WSDL or all of the generated classes it's impossible to help you. The best you can do is comparing the generated classes that work with those that don't work. Make sure you use the -Xnocompile or -keep options with wsimport so that you have access to the generated Java source.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added my finding below. Please respond on the same.